# Ms Graph read messages gives ErrorAccesDenied

Tags: .net, api, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to Read my messages with GraphClient using InteractiveAuthenticationProvider from Microsoft.Graph.Auth namespace
with a PublicClientApplication from Microsoft.Identity.Client.

It gives me Code: ErrorAccesDenied
Message: Acces is denied. Check Credentials and try again.
As soon as I Call .Result

---

```
strin userId = <User Id>
var redirectUri = "http://localhost";
string clientId = <Client ID>
string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                                        .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                                        .Build();

var authentication = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(app, scopes);
var client = new GraphServiceClient(authentication);
var messages = client.Users[userId].Messages.Request().GetAsync().Result; // <- Error Here Because of the .Result
```

I put all the scopes that I could in my app permission : User.Read, User.Read.All, Mail.Read, MailboxSettings.Read... for application and delegated permissions. And They all have been granted Admin Consent.
Also, when I Don't use the Message attribute in my Request it works fine.

Then I Tried adding a WithAuthority() method with a tenantId. So the line became like this.

```
string tenantId = <Tenant Id>
var app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
                                            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, tenantId)
                                            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                                            .Build();
```

Then as soon as I called .Result it gave me a different Error.
Code : OrganisationFromTenantGuidNotFound
Message : the tenant for tenant guid "Tenant Id" does not exist
But this also Works when I Don't put the Message attribute. So I'm wondering how can I use The Message attribute to read my messages thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this [Get message API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request), the delegation permission you required is `Mail.ReadBasic, Mail.Read` and the application permission is `Mail.ReadBasic.All, Mail.Read`.

```
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .Build();

InteractiveAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
var message = await graphClient.Me.Messages.Request().GetAsync();
```

Here is the [sample](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2020/01/graph-client-authentication-provider/) about Interactive Authentication you could refer to.